# Hausdorff Distance Confusion

Tags: metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

I was confused about something really basic about Hausdorff distances and was wondering if someone could clarify.

Let $A \subset X $ be a non-empty set, and $a \in A$. Suppose further that $x \in X$.

Since the Hausdorff distance is a metric, it satisfies the triangle inequality. Can I say that

$$ d(x,a) \le d(x, A) +d(a, A) = d(x,A) \, ? $$
I know this isn't right. Where have I gone wrong? Can I not apply the triangle inequality like this, and if so, why can't I?

Comment: Where exactly is the Hausdorff distance here even? The Hausdorff distance is defined between two sets in a metric space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a\in X, B \subset X$, I think you're getting confused between
$$d(a,B) = \inf_{b \in B} d(a,b)$$
which *isn't* the Hausdorff metric, and
$$d_H(\{a\}, B)$$
which is the only way I can see to interpret $d(a,B) $ as a Hausdorff metric.

You should re-check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), but unless $A = \{a\}$, $d_H(\{a\}, A)$ is not automatically zero. It's because, speaking roughly, there are points in $A$ that are some distance away from $a$.

Also, you're okay with singleton sets, so writing $d_H(\{x\}, \{y\}) $as $d(x,y)$ for your first term is valid, although likely to lead you astray. But once you dropped the "$d_H$" for "$d$" in the second half of the triangle inequality, you were doomed. :-)